# Creating a python spellchecker using tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, spell-checking, tkinter-entry, tkinter-text

For school, I need to create a spell checker, using python. I decided to do it using a GUI created with tkinter. I need to be able to input a text (.txt) file that will be checked, and a dictionary file, also a text file. The program needs to open both files, check the check file against the dictionary file, and then display any words that are misspelled.

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename

def checkFile():
    # get the sequence of words from a file
    text = open(file_ent.get())
    dictDoc = open(dict_ent.get())

    for ch in '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~':
        text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
    words = text.split()

    # make a dictionary of the word counts
    wordDict = {}
    for w in words:
        wordDict[w] = wordDict.get(w,0) + 1

    for k in dictDict:
        dictDoc.pop(k, None)
    misspell_lbl["text"] = dictDoc

# Set-up the window
window = tk.Tk()
window.title("Temperature Converter")
window.resizable(width=False, height=False)

# Setup Layout
frame_a = tk.Frame(master=window)
file_lbl = tk.Label(master=frame_a, text="File Name")
space_lbl = tk.Label(master=frame_a, width = 6)
dict_lbl =tk.Label(master=frame_a, text="Dictionary File")
file_lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
space_lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
dict_lbl.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

frame_b = tk.Frame(master=window)
file_ent = tk.Entry(master=frame_b, width=20)
dict_ent = tk.Entry(master=frame_b, width=20)
file_ent.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
dict_ent.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

check_btn = tk.Button(master=window, text="Spellcheck", command=checkFile)

frame_c = tk.Frame(master=window)
message_lbl = tk.Label(master=frame_c, text="Misspelled Words:")
misspell_lbl = tk.Label(master=frame_c, text="")
message_lbl.pack()
misspell_lbl.pack()

frame_a.pack()
frame_b.pack()
check_btn.pack()
frame_c.pack()

# Run the application
window.mainloop()
```

I want the file to check against the dictionary and display the misspelled words in the misspell_lbl.

The test files I'm using to make it work, and to submit with the assignment are here:

[check file](https://replit.com/@JamesBrummett/finalproject1#Turtlesong.txt)
[dictionary file](https://replit.com/@JamesBrummett/finalproject1#english.txt)

I preloaded the files to the site that I'm submitting this on, so it should just be a matter of entering the file name and extension, not the entire path.

I'm pretty sure the problem is with my function to read and check the file, I've been beating my head on a wall trying to solve this, and I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is `dictDict`? It's not defined anywhere.

Comment: You've described what you're building, but you haven't asked a question. What do you need help with? Why do you think your program isn't working? Is it throwing an error, and if so, what is the error?

Comment: @Henry That was supposed to be dicDoc: I fixed it after I saw it and I guess I copied the old code with that typo still in it.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley My question is how to make this work. I know my function for reading the files and spell checking is a hot mess, Is there a better way to make a function that opens the files, reads them, and then spell checks?

Comment: Why do you think it's not working? Why do you think you need a better way, and how do you define "better"? What is it doing, and how is it different from what you expect? You haven't given us many clues as to what the real problem is. Stackoverflow isn't designed for "please fix my code"-type questions. You need to be more specific.

Comment: This is the error it's throwing me right now;

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "main.py", line 26, in checkFile
    text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'replace'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem is with how you try to read the files. `open(...)` will return a `_io.TextIOWrapper` object, not a string and this is what causes your error. To get the text from the file, you need to use `.read()`, like this:

```
def checkFile():
    # get the sequence of words from a file
    with open(file_ent.get()) as f:
      text = f.read()
    with open(dict_ent.get()) as f:
      dictDoc = f.read().splitlines()
```

The `with open(...) as f` part gives you a file object called `f`, and automatically closes the file when it's done. This is more concise version of

```
f = open(...)
text = f.read()
f.close()
```

`f.read()` will get the text from the file. For the dictionary I also added `.splitlines()` to turn the newline separated text into a list. 
I couldn't really see where you'd tried to check for misspelled words, but you can do it with a list comprehension.

```
misspelled = [x for x in words if x not in dictDoc]
```

This gets every word which is not in the dictionary file and adds it to a list called `misspelled`. Altogether, the `checkFile` function now looks like this, and works as expected:

```
def checkFile():
    # get the sequence of words from a file
    with open(file_ent.get()) as f:
      text = f.read()
    with open(dict_ent.get()) as f:
      dictDoc = f.read().splitlines()

    for ch in '!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~':
        text = text.replace(ch, ' ')
    words = text.split()

    # make a dictionary of the word counts
    wordDict = {}
    for w in words:
        wordDict[w] = wordDict.get(w,0) + 1
    
    misspelled = [x for x in words if x not in dictDoc]

    misspell_lbl["text"] = misspelled
```